# How can I turn off Macbook screen instantly?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I use Mac OS X (10.7.5)

I wonder how I can turn off screen only of my MacBook 
without closing the lid, without waiting for the screensaver.
The best way I can currently do is just to close the lid or to repeat 'F1' key to dim it.

Is there any shortcut key to do so?
I use this frequently when I read a book or a paper with the laptop turned on (not sleeping) to avoid distraction.

Comment: One thing I do is I configure a "Hot Corner" (bottom right, in my case) to invoke the screen saver instantly.  Load the System Preferences, go to Mission Control, click Hot Corners at bottom, and then select the corner you want to customize and choose Start Screen Saver.  Then, when you move your pointer to that corner of the screen, the screen saver will start automatically.